# How can I download SOILGRIDS v2 data through WCS in EPSG:4326, keeping (as close as possible) to the native 250m resolution?

Tags: wgs84, resolution, wcs, soilgrids, marinus

SOILGRIDS data are currently available at 250m resolution. The resolution needs to be specified as part of the WCS download request, e.g. (Python MWE from https://git.wur.nl/isric/soilgrids/soilgrids.notebooks/-/blob/master/02-WCS-getExtent.ipynb):

```py
from owslib.wcs import WebCoverageService
wcs = WebCoverageService('http://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/phh2o.map', version='1.0.0')

response = wcs.getCoverage(
    identifier='phh2o_0-5cm_mean', 
    crs='urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::152160',
    bbox=(-1784000, 1356000, -1140000, 1863000), 
    resx=250, resy=250,          # resolution [m]
    format='GEOTIFF_INT16')

with open('Senegal_pH_0-5_mean.tif', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.read())
```

Coarser and finer resolutions can be specified too, leading to aggregated (this is easy to check) and interpolated (presumably, because the request completes but differences are very small between 250m and finer resolution maps) maps.

If I want to download the same data in EPSG:4326, some changes are needed to the code:

```py
response = wcs.getCoverage(
    identifier='phh2o_0-5cm_mean', 
    crs='urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326',
    bbox=(lon_min, lat_min, lon_max, lat_max), 
    resx=??, resy=??,            # resolution, needs to be in degrees now
    format='GEOTIFF_INT16')
```

I assume that these downloads use a reprojection of the 250m source data and are not an independent dataset but could not find any information about this. Is this correct? If so, is there a way to specify `resx` and `resy` that minimizes aggregation/interpolation compared to the source data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tackling each part of the question:

### Interpolation

This WCS is set up with MapServer, with all interpolation and aggregation operations handled on the fly by the software. MapServer also conducts projections, using the PROJ library. On the hard drive only the original maps exist (Homolosine projection).

### Resolution

A product like SoilGrids should never be used with the Marinus projection. The distortions are massive and there is no technical reason forcing its use. That said, the distortions can be minimised by setting the cell side of the output to 250 meters at the central latitude of the area of interest. This can be approximated with a simple expression:

`resX = 250 / (2*pi*a/360) / cos(phi)`

Where `a` is the major axis of the WGS84 datum (6378137 meters). So if the middle latitude of
your area of interest is 50º N, then the value for `resX` would be
0.003428.

As for the northing resolution the distortion is much smaller, ignoring it is a valid option. A single conversion can be applied everywhere:

`resY = 250 / (2*pi*b/360)`

Where `b` is the minor axis, which minimises distortion at the poles. Applying `a` in the `resY` conversion minimises distortion at the equator instead. With `(a + b) / 2` distortion is minimised at middle latitudes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just to be complete, should the same equation be applied to find `resX` using longitude and minor axis `b = 6356752` meters?

Comment: @bumbling_geographer I expanded and corrected the answer.

Comment: I actually found this was not possible, so I eventually preferred to download in EPSG:28992 and reproject in EPSG:4326.
However, you refer *version 2* in your question but your example specifically states `version='1.0.0'`

Comment: @Newbielp There is no version referenced in this answer. To make it clear: at this moment only version 2.0 maps are being served through WCS/WMS. None of these maps are available in the Dutch system, since it uses a different (and much older) datum. Any transformations of these maps to/from the Dutch system will yield massive errors.

Comment: I do not understand it. 1) `wcs = WebCoverageService('http://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/phh2o.map', version='1.0.0')` refers to a version and I just typed `version='2.0.0'`. 2) I tried the above with EPSG:4326 but it did not give me any data. If I run it with EPSG:28992 I get plenty of data. 3) It is documented that there is ostensibly one more argument `crs_response` where I tried to call the data with 4326, but it did not work either. Overall, the only system with which I managed to download data was the Dutch system.

Comment: The version you are referring to is the service (WCS), not the maps. You can verify in the `getCapabilities` document, the Dutch system is not offered by the service, but the EPSG:4326 datum ensemble is: [https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/phh2o.map&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities](https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/phh2o.map&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities).